# kind-kind User in Kind cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kind

I created a Kind cluster with the command 'kind create cluster'. This creates a user named kind-kind.I would like to know his permissions. I did not see any rolebinding or clusterrolebinding grant to him.

Comment: You'll need to include more details explaining what you saw and what a successful answer to your question would look like; the short version is that kind writes an x509 pair into the location [pointed to by `--kubeconfig`](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/blob/v0.9.0/pkg/cmd/kind/create/cluster/createcluster.go#L63) (by default `$HOME/.kube/config`) with `cluster-admin` privileges, just like a traditional cluster

Comment: Thanks! I saw a reference to kind-kind user in .kube/config but I did not see a role-binding  for it so I was not sure what's his privileges.

Comment: The cluster-admin is a built-in Role, and authentication is provided by the `O = system:masters` present in that certificate